# Дерево в базе

Tags: mysqli, sql, структуры, mysql

**Как лучше хранить дерево в базе?**

Есть подразделения, у каждого подразделения может быть несколько своих подразделений (*стандартное дерево*). В ходе работы необходимо будет:

1. Вывести всю структуру;
2. Вывести наивысшее родительское подразделение;
3. Найти список всех дочерних подразделений.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

ну самое простое

```
id  |  name  |  parent
1   |  first |  0
2   |  second|  1
3   |  one   |  1
4   |  two   |  0
5   |  blah  |  4
```

Собственно parent - это родитель 0 - корень, число - кто предок. Все просто.

Исходя из выше написанного у ID 1 есть 2 потомка,у 2 нет, у тройки нет, у 4нет , у5 один.
Вывод тоже простой

```
select * from table where parent='0' // все родители
select * from table where parent='1' // все потомки от родителя с id 1
```

+ тут возможно делать вложенность любую, но это уже другая история и для нее лучше использовать другую структуру

а так для обозрения

```
id  |  name  |  parent
1   |  first |  0
2   |  second|  1
3   |  one   |  1
4   |  two   |  2
5   |  blah  |  3
```

1 умеет 2 потомков, но и id 2 и 3 имеют по 1 потомку, вот вложенность.

Comment: собственно, имея запись (5 ; p5 ; 4), чтобы добраться до верхнего уровня, необходимо сделать несколько запросов?:

id  |  name  |  parent

1   |  p1    |  0

2   |  p2    |  1

3   |  p3    |  2

4   |  p4    |  3

5   |  p5    |  4

* where id='4'
* where id='3'
* where id='2'
* where id='1'

если глубина увеличиться, то кол-во запросов увеличиться, не слижком ли это будет загружать сервер?

Comment: а ты правильно ответ прочитал?

>+ тут возможно делать вложенность любую, но это уже другая история и для нее лучше использовать другую структуру

и не id а parent! в большей части он тут используется для выборок.

+ ко всему это решение для твоего вопроса - самое быстрое решение и думать о миллионах запросах в БД тут и смысла нет! Не нравится решение смотри в сторону **nested sets** там тебе в руки больше геморроя с твоей простой структурой данных. Ты хочешь сказать что у тебя миллион подразделений и миллион вложенностей в них? Что за компания такая?

Comment: Ты задал вопрос, получил ответ. зачем лезть в дебри и задавать вопросы не по существу заданного вопроса?

Comment: собственно, вопрос я задавал "как лучше". и дело не в том, нравится / не нравится , метод то нравится, и на данный момент его использую. Но данный метод, при решении поставленных задач, приводит к множественным запросам. я считаю, что "производительность" метода хранения не выходит за границы заданного вопроса.

Comment: Если это внутренний проект, то не вижу смысла думать про производительность, ибо в конторе наверное есть нормальные сервер, который справится с миллионами запросов. А так смотри тогда в другую сторону, я написал другой вариант.

Comment: В целях уменьшения количества запросов, вместо нескольких по каждому уровню вложенности, можно добавить дополнительные поля. parent0 - родитель нулевого уровня. Для получения всех детей, внуков, правнуков и т.д. можно добавить parents - строка вида ",1,2,3,4,5,", с которой можно сравнивать like'ом `where parents like '%,'+4+',%'`.  
При этом:

* усложняется изменение подчиненности элементов, но в данном случае, думается это совсем не критично структура подразделений одна, и может только расти по идее. 
* скорость для запросов с parents не так велика.

Answer (score 2):

[Деревья в поддерживающих стандарты SQL базах данных на sql.ru](http://www.sql.ru/articles/mssql/2005/061904treesinsqldatabases.shtml)